# Redirect to a previously visited URL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I’m working on a MVC 5 (asp) application. One of the requirements I get is to have multiple navigation paths to point at the same destination page. The problem is going back to a previous page after a post according to the navigation history of the user. 
Let’s consider a basic scenario of three webpages

Customers/ShowAll -> Show a list of all customers

Customers /Search -> Show a list of customers according to a search (name, country …)

Customers /Update/1134 -> Show the update page for a specific customer (i.e. customer_id=1134)

So the navigation path goes like this

ShowAll -> Update

or

Search -> Update

If the user navigates to “Customers /Search” then “Customers /Update/1134”, updates the customer information and saves the data, I want the server to redirect to the page “Customers /Search” since it’s the path the user uses. 
This is a very basic case but it can be more complex like going back many pages and always return a previously visited page (or a default one if no pages match the history).

**What I’ve done so far**

I have created a prototype that keeps track of the navigation history of a user on the server side. It uses session storage on the client side to give a unique id for the current browser tab. On each page unload it adds the browser tab id to the cookies. Then on the server side there’s a dictionary (in the session) with the tab id (extracted from the cookies) as the key and a list of visited URLs as the value. The current URL is added to the list of URLs. I found this solution to be working but it has some flaws.

1. If JavaScript is disabled this solution won’t work (this is not a very big deal since I can require all the users to turn it on (it’s an intranet for a small company))
2. If a tab is duplicated the resulting two tabs will have the same id. This is due to the implementation of session storage (at least on Chrome). So the history on the server can get corrupted if the user uses both tabs.
3. I store the dictionary of history in a session variable so if the session timed out, the history is lost. I thought about keeping the history in the database but I feel it’s a little of overheat for the database.

A last thing is that the dictionary of URLs is limited to the last 30 pages visited since I want to limit the server memory. It’s not important to my question but I feel to mention it since I’m sure some of you may see the problem of keep all pages from all users for all tabs in history.

I also thought of a similar solution using cookies to transmit the last 30 pages visited on each request and have the server parse this history when it needs it. Only the pages from the application domain will be kept. This will resolve the problem of persistence after a session times out but it introduce a little more processing to the server since the history will be parsed in about each request.
I want to know if there a better solution to redirect the user according to navigation history. Maybe there’s a build-in functionality in MVC 5 that I don’t know.

Thanks for any advice.

Regards.

Comment: Can you just pass the return action as a parameter to the Update action?  Also, have you considered trying to use the HTTP_REFERER header?

Comment: I thought about passing the return action but I sometimes have to pass it throught multiple controllers so the redirect can be a few pages back (i.e. path A->B->C an then redirect to A). So its a pain to manage manually for all possible paths. Also for the same reason  HTTP_REFERER  only refers to the previous page an I may need more history than that. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Using session state (as you have discovered) is not a very good solution to this problem because:

1. It times out, in which case the data is lost.
2. If the user doesn't navigate to the page the way you expect (for example, coming directly to a page via Google SERP), then it doesn't work.

The only way to make it work 100% of the time is to put all of the navigation identifier information into the URL so the system can determine how to build the navigation links.

There is no built-in functionality for this in MVC 5, but you could use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) to solve your issue. It contains HTML helpers for Menu and SiteMapPath, which acts like a breadcrumb trail.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu()
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

It works on a different principle - it loads a single shared hierarchy of nodes (a site map) into memory. Then each request that comes in matches one of the nodes and uses the map to determine how to build the links in the HTML helpers. There is no session state used at all.

The trick to getting it to work in your scenario is to make the `Customers/Update/1134` page available on 2 different URLs. Then you can configure 2 different node hierarchies and it will know which one to match based on the routing information.

For example, you could add an additional route value that indicates that the page you are navigating from is the search page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Customer 1134", "Update", "Customers", new { source = "Search" }, null)
```

By default, this will build a URL like `Customers/Update/1134?source=Search`. You can make it look prettier by adjusting your route configuration.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchSource",
            url: "Search/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { source = "Search", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ShowAllSource",
            url: "ShowAll/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { source = "ShowAll", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Now with the same ActionLink shown above, you will get the URL `/Search/Customers/Update/1134`. That's better. Note that when you put the `ActionLink` on your `ShowAll` page, it should be like this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Customer 1134", "Update", "Customers", new { source = "ShowAll" }, null)
```

Then when you set up the node configuration in `MvcSiteMapProvider`, you need to make 2 different parent nodes, like this.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">

    <!-- Additional nodes here -->

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Search" controller="Customers" action="Search">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Update Customer" controller="Customers" action="Update" source="Search" preservedRouteParameters="id"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Show All Customers" controller="Customers" action="ShowAll">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Update Customer" controller="Customers" action="Update" source="ShowAll" preservedRouteParameters="id"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>

    <!-- Additional nodes here -->

</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

You will then get a complete navigation solution:

```
/Customers/ShowAll                  | Home > Show All Customers
/ShowAll/Customers/Update/1134      | Home > Show All Customers > Update Customer
/Customers/Search                   | Home > Search
/Search/Customers/Update/1134       | Home > Search > Update Customer
```

Of course, this is just an example. You can make the URLs and navigation links look any way you want.

### Redirecting Back

Finally, there is redirecting back to the location the user came from. That's easy because `MvcSiteMapProvider` keeps track of the parent node.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(CustomerModel model)
{
    // Update customer here...

    var currentNode = this.GetCurrentSiteMapNode();
    if (currentNode != null)
    {
        var parentNode = currentNode.ParentNode;
        if (parentNode != null)
        {
            return Redirect(parentNode.Url);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

You may wish to store some additional information (sort order, search term, etc) from the original parent page, in which case you will need to pass those parameters through the Update page and back to the parent page somehow.

One way is to use session and then use some logical default behavior if they are missing when you get to the redirect page.

Another (easier) approach is to add them as parameters (query string or route values) to the URL of the Customer Update page so they will automatically be built into the return URL. Since you have 2 different routes, you would just need to add the information to the appropriate route. You just need to ensure both the routes of the Search page and the Customer Update page include them so the parent URL is built appropriately.

> **Full Disclosure:** I am a major contributor of the `MvcSiteMapProvider` project.

See also:

- https://github.com/maartenba/mvcsitemapprovider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page
- http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/07/MvcSiteMapProvider-40-a-test-drive
- http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position

Comment: Very nice library! I only have a concern, if I have a navigation path like A->B->C->D and I want to redirect to A from D, I have to pass the query string (source=A) from A to B to C to D right ? If so, for my usecase, I fear that this can be complex to manage, but again maybe I missed something.

Comment: When adding a node for every single page (which is possible using dynamic node providers), the nodes are completely independent of one another, so you don't have to share anything between them. However, when using `preservedRouteParameters` as in the example, the deepest node in the hierarchy requires all of the optional parameters (those that are not action, controller, or area) of its ancestry in order to build all of the ancestor URLs. The only place where you need to pass the information is when constructing the `ActionLink`s for each list of items.